# Replacements for some BLToolkit classes or methods missing in LinqToDB

Tags: c#, .net, orm, linq2db, bltoolkit

I'm migrating from BLToolkit to LinqToDB. And I couldn't find replacements for some classes or methods missing in LinqToDB.

1. `IDataContext.Delete()` and `IDataContext.InsertOrReplace()` cannot accept `IEnumerable<T>` anymore. Is iterating over entities collection and using `db.InsertOrReplace(inputEntities[i])` the only option? Isn't that a performance hit?
2. In our class derived from `MappingSchema` in some cases instead of our custom conversions we used `base.ConvertChangeType()`. Now it's missing - what is supposed to be used instead?
3. We used `dbManager.SetCommand(command, params).Prepare()` - Prepare is missing now. How to prepare command for execution?
4. `IObjectFactory.CreateInstance` has no `InitContext context` argument anymore. How to obtain `context.MappingSchema`, `context.DataSource` and `context.SourceObject` now?
5. In BLToolkit we used `SqlQueryInfo` to change parameter names in query like that:

```
public static void SetCommand<TEntity>([NotNull] this DbManager dbManager, TEntity entity, string actionName)
{
    var queryInfo = new SqlQuery<TEntity>(dbManager).GetSqlQueryInfo(dbManager, typeof(TEntity), actionName);
    var queryText = queryInfo.QueryText;
    var parameters = queryInfo.GetParameters(dbManager, entity);
    for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        var parameterName = parameters[i].ParameterName;
        //Parameters and Where-clause for primary key
        if (parameterName.EndsWith("_P") || parameterName.EndsWith("_W"))
        {
            var newName = parameterName.Substring(0, parameterName.Length - 2);
            queryText = queryText.Replace(parameterName, newName);
            parameters[i].ParameterName = newName;
        }
    }
    dbManager.SetCommand(queryText, parameters);
}
```

`SqlQuery` and `SqlQueryInfo` are missing - what to use instead?